# relation between original columns indexes and columns indexes after sorting in datatables

Tags: datatables

I need to find relation between original columns indexes and columns indexes after sorting in datatables .
say we have an ordinary html table :

```html
<table id="namesTable">
   <thead>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Jim</td>
          <td>Andrew</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Rodriguez</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Manau</td>
          <td>Lara</td>
       </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

after calling :

```js
$('#namesTable').DataTable(
'order' : [[0 , 'Desc']]
);
```

is there any way to have like a dictionnary that says that index 0 is now2 and 1 is now 0 and 2 is now 1  after ordering ?

any help is welcome !

Comment: It seems to me that dataTables do this already, when using `index()` -> http://jsfiddle.net/d6tcLtha/ does `index()` not return the original position?

Comment: thanks a lot it's exactly what i was looking for , make it as an answer so i accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataTables [**`row().index()`**](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) or [**`rows().indexes()`**](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().indexes()) returns the original index, eg how the rows are ordered in the underlying HTML. To get the row index from the example above :

```js
$('#namesTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    alert(table.row(this).index());
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d6tcLtha/**